# Rails, simple_form and nested_models with a customised association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, associations, simple-form, nested-forms

I am using simple_form's [nested models](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/wiki/Nested-Models) but I am hitting an issue with a customised Rails association like, for example:

```
belongs_to :exclusive_club, -> { where(exclusive_clubs: {status: true}) }
```

My form is fine and everything is working correctly. So, I have not included any more code than above but let me know if anything else is needed to aid a solution. However, as some of you may have guessed, the issue I am having is when I attempt to use my form on an exclusive_club with a status of false, the fields I want to update are not present.

Is there a way around this issue while retaining my association?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can override the belogs_to lambda. So the solution is to either move the lambda into a separate scope, or use another belongs_to with a different lambda. Could do it like that:

`belongs_to :exclusive_club_false, class_name: "ExclusiveClub", foreign_key: 'exclusive_club_id', -> { where(exclusive_clubs: {status: false})}`